# SoapUI property transfer of content from test response body to another test request url

Tags: json, soapui

I'm trying to figure out how to transfer an ID from a JSON-response in one SoapUI test to use in the url request of another test. The case is to do a post which creates an entry, and then do a get on another endpoint to see that the previous post was ok.

JSON example:

```
<Response xmlns="http://localhost/equipment">
   <beskrivelse>description</beskrivelse>
   <id>19</id>
   <navn>name</navn>
   <plassering>rom2</plassering>
</Response>
```

So basically i want to grab the number 19 and use this in a get to localhost/equipment/19.

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Are you transferring this property between different **tests**, or between test **steps** within one test?

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline [property expansion](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/property-expansion.html). So in the place where you need the value, you would right-click and select the correct value from the step. You would end up with something that looks like `${<test_step_name>#Response#//*:id}`.